# Tensor product of fields and homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, tensor-products

## Question

I'm pretty confused about changing the base field of a tensor product. For example, if $E/F,L/F$ are field extensions, the $E\otimes_F L$ could be seen as a vector space over $E$, by imposing an extra scalar multiplication: $e'(e\otimes l)=(e'e)\otimes l$. I have no prior experience about reasoning this, so I ask for a reference or bibliography for such behavior.

## Background

In Morandi's Field and Galois Theory, there's an ordinary theorem on linear disjointness:

> Let $K,L$ be extension fields of $F$, and let $E$ be a field with $F\subseteq E\subseteq K$. Then $K,L$ are linearly disjoint over $F$ if and only if $E,L$ are linearly disjoint over $F$ and $K,EL$ are linearly disjoint over $E$.

It's a common theorem, say, on Hungerford or Lang's Algebra. However, the proof on Morandi's seems different, based on the sequence of *natural* homomorphisms:

$$K\otimes_FL\to K\otimes_E(E\otimes_FL)\to K\otimes_EEL\to K[L]$$

It seems that the proof is based on a formal reasoning on the diagram. It's somewhat more abstract than Lang's or Hungerford's. However, the second one seems illegal, since $E\otimes_FL$ is an $F$-vector space but the outer tensor product is $\otimes_E$. I asked Morandi by email, and he replied that $E\otimes_F L$ could be seen as an $E$-vector space by $e'(e\otimes l)=(e'e)\otimes l$. It seems okay, but since I'm quite unfamiliar with tensor product, I don't know what to check (for example, well-definedness or compatibility), so I ask for some request on this strange behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key words: [extension of scalars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_of_scalars).

Comment: Is that fairly involved and is the proposition trivial under this kind of knowledge?? At a first glance, it seems intricate to me, so I need to learn more to assimilate it, and wikipedia doesn't furnish enough references.

Comment: @YACP Thanks. It doesn't seem a piece of cake.